# Drive udeploy deployment from Rally

Tags: rally, continuous-deployment, agile, udeploy

We are using Rally to track the SDLC and IBM Urban Code Deployer for deployments. Is it possible to integrate Rally with udeploy so that when the status of a user story changes, the udeploy application is triggered and artifacts pertaining to that user story only is deployed to the target environment?. For SCM, we are using GitHub.

Please suggest.

Thanks.
Kumarjit

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is Rally's Webhooks, which is in beta.

https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/manage-webhooks

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/pigeon/docs/webhooks

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: Thanks, but honestly I do not have any idea on how to setup webhook. I went through the documentation given, but did not figure out much. What do I need to do to setup a webhook between Rally and Udeploy server?